# a box with a *pointer* with just CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do we use just CSS to achieve the effects shown in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/smWmQ.gif (I'm sure that image is created with CSS because I visited that site with images disabled in Chrome)

Comment: What site's this from? You can reverse engineer pretty easily with Firebug or some other browser code inspector.

Comment: you can, but it is a serious work with css. you can use large borders to do so. but an image is just so much easier

Comment: i've forgotten which page i got it from.. its a site that encourages us to use CSS for this kind of things

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple very efficient way of doing it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bseze/)

UPDATE:

Here is an example:

the html

```
<div>
    <span class='tip'></span>
</div>
```

the css

```
div { 
    height: 30px;
    width:50px;
}
.tip {
    display:block;
    width:1px;
    heigth:20px;
    border-left: 30px solid #fff;
    border-right: 30px solid #fff;
    border-top: 25px solid #F00;
}
```

Comment: Hey that's a cool solution.  You should post the general gist of it here though.

Answer (score 0):

There is something similar I took from the [jQuery Ketchup plugin](http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/).
The CSS looks like this:

```
.box span {
    border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6) transparent -moz-use-text-color;
    border-left: 0 solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-style: solid solid none;
    border-width: 10px 15px 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 0;
}

.box ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: #111111;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

The according HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Also have a look at the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Daff/hpjyN/).

Comment: 1st links is dead!

Answer (score 0):

The triangle you see is just a box, often with no size, with really degenerate and different `border-width`s. For example to make an upward-pointing triangle, you would make a make a box like so:

```
      top
     _____
left| / \ |right
    |/___\|
     bottom
```

The box has no size, a `top-border-width` of 0, and non-zero values for the other widths. The border-color of the left and right and top are transparent, so you can't see those triangles. All you can see is the bottom border.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/NnGyv/

Unfortunately, you cannot use percentages with border widths, or else you could achieve a reusable CSS class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers can do this automatically with [HTML5 validation](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html). You won't have much control over how it looks but it's 1000x easier to code and works without Javascript.

If you want more visual control there's [jQuery Tools Validator](http://flowplayer.org/tools/validator/index.html). Although this uses Javascript it should fall back to HTML5 if Javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The original site may be using HTML5.

HTML5 has some pretty neat features for client-side form validation. This looks very much like Chrome's take on an input box with the "required" attribute set. You'll also note a placeholder (another HTML5 attribute).

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pzthh/). You can find out more information from [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html).